# Borderless pdf extraction to json is not working properly for Python camelot library

Tags: python, pdf-extraction, python-camelot

Can anyone give me quick answer/help that
as we are facing some issue after pdf extraction to json using python camelot is not giving exact content. some content is missing after extraction.

Comment: Please post the PDF and what you tried.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vernt20ntt1z8rt/essart_wochenpla_zwei%20Scheibenhaus%20%281%29.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code:

```
import camelot

pdf_path = '/YOUR/FILEPATH.pdf'
tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf_path, flavor='stream')
```

[image]

Here are two problems:

- headers font is not properly read, so you find strange characters like `(cid:71)`...
- using `flavor='lattice'`, the table isn't detected. Using `flavor='stream'`, the table is detected, but the cells aren't properly detected.

At the moment, I think that Camelot can't properly extract this table.
They are working on fixing the second problem (see [this](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/192) and [this](https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot/issues/10)).

Comment: same problem happened with me too

Comment: I am sorry that this problem can't be solved using Camelot. If my answer Is useful, please mark It as accepted and upvote It.

Comment: is there any other library so that we can solve this?

Comment: But extracttable.com is for image to other format. We need pdf to json.